# Intermittent Error while getting WorksetInfo from a BIM 360 Model

Tags: vb.net, revit-api

I'm using Autodesk.Revit.DB.**WorksharingUtils.GetUserWorksetInfo**(ModelPath) to get a list of Worksets from a model. This has worked flawlessly on local server and Revit Server projects for several years. This year we are adding capabilities to link BIM 360 models. So now **I'm querying a model in BIM 360**. Sometimes it works without error. But every once in a while it fails and I see in the journal file that it fails on this method.

I suspect that it is a timing thing or maybe the file in BIM 360 hasn't completely finished updating from previous activities (like syncing and closing). But I don't know how to deal with that possibility. I've tried pausing the program to see if that helps. It doesn't.

Here's essentially what I'm doing:

```
`' open the host model
  aDoc = OpenCloudModelWithCallback(mApp, modelPath)

' Open a Transaction
  Dim mTransaction As New Transaction(aDoc)
  mTransaction.Start("Linking Models")

'Revit Server (and BIM 360) cannot use relative path
  Dim linkOptions As New RevitLinkOptions(True)
  linkOptions.IsRelative = False

' FileInfo is a local class created to store information about Revit models
For Each f As FileInfo In LinkList

' Don't load "Shared Levels and Grids"
  Dim linkedWorksets As IList(Of WorksetPreview) = WorksharingUtils.GetUserWorksetInfo(f.Modelpath)

  Dim worksetIds As IList(Of WorksetId) = New List(Of WorksetId)()
    ' Find worksetName
    For Each worksetPrev As WorksetPreview In linkedWorksets
      If worksetPrev.Name.CompareTo("Shared Levels and Grids") <> 0 Then
        worksetIds.Add(worksetPrev.Id)
      End If
    Next

  Dim linkWorksetConfig As New WorksetConfiguration(WorksetConfigurationOption.CloseAllWorksets)
  linkWorksetConfig.Open(worksetIds)
  linkOptions.SetWorksetConfiguration(linkWorksetConfig)

  'link in the BIM 360 model
  linkResult = RevitLinkType.Create(aDoc, f.Modelpath, linkOptions)

Next

  ' End Transaction
  mTransaction.Commit()
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this? Or how I might troubleshoot an intermittent error?

Comment: Generally when asking for help with an error, telling what the error actually is can be quite useful.  Would also help if you could tell us where exactly in the above method that exception occurs.  If it is a timing issue, could you implement a Re-try (Combo of loop and try/catch maybe )mechanise introducing a small delay?

Comment: You are quite right, of course. The onscreen error is the standard "Revit could not complete the external command. Contact the provider for assitance ...". In the journal file, I found the point where that message is displayed, and working backward from there, the first thing I find is a reference to the WorksharingUtils.getUserWorksetInfo method being called from my AddRevitLink subroutine. \n That's really all I have to go on. I'm a bit of a Stackoverflow newbie, otherwise I would include screen captures or attach a journal file.

Comment: Is this problem replicable in a development environment or does it only happen in production? If in Dev environment some standard debugging might help.  If only in production I would suggest building some additional logging into this method which may be able to help get the exact point of failure and more details about the problem.